# How to write jQuery code or call jQuery function in onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't this simple code work?

```
<div onClick="myFunction()"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function myFunction(){
       alert("sss");
    }
})
```

The JS file is external and it's called in the `head` of my HTML page. The jQuery library is added before that.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work as functions called from the `on*` event attributes need to be within scope of the `window`. Your code places the function within the jQuery document.ready handler instead. Try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert("sss");
}
```

```html
<div onClick="myFunction()">Click me</div>
```

You should note though, that using `on*` event attributes is considered outdated for this reason, amongst many. You should instead use unobtrusive JS code to attach your event handlers, either in native JS:

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("sss");
});
```

```html
<div>Click me</div>
```

Or jQuery, as you seem to be using it already:

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').on('click', function() {
    alert("sss");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Go and read tutorials of html and Jquery at some tutorial websites like [This](https://www.w3schools.com/) or [thisone](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/).

and answer to your code is

HTML

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    alert('Hello');
}
```

Assuming you included JQuery libraries.